# How to fix Gitlab CE 14.1.6 upgrade failed

Tags: gitlab

I wanted to update my GitLab CE installed on a EC2 instance following the recommendation. I went from 13.0.x to 13.9.2 -> 13.12.12 -> 14.0.11 -> 14.1.6 as the documentation recommend.

Every time I check if the server was responding. I just had to restart the process when I jump to 14.X.
But when I went to 14.1.6 I got an error on the update :

```
[...]
System Info:
    ------------
    chef_version=15.17.4
    platform=ubuntu
    platform_version=20.04
    ruby=ruby 2.7.4p191 (2021-07-07 revision a21a3b7d23) [x86_64-linux]
    program_name=/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chef-client
    executable=/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chef-client

Recipe: gitlab::gitlab-rails
  * execute[clear the gitlab-rails cache] action run
    - execute /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake cache:clear
Recipe: gitaly::enable
  * runit_service[gitaly] action restart (up to date)
  * runit_service[gitaly] action hup
    - send hup to runit_service[gitaly]

Running handlers:
There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:

rails_migration[gitlab-rails] (gitlab::database_migrations line 51) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: bash[migrate gitlab-rails database] (/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/resources/rails_migration.rb line 16) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20211028-68712-eysjor" ----
STDOUT: rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Expected batched background migration for the given configuration to be marked as 'finished', but it is 'active':   {:job_class_name=>"CopyColumnUsingBackgroundMigrationJob", :table_name=>"events", :column_name=>"id", :job_arguments=>[["id"], ["id_convert_to_bigint"]]}

Finalize it manualy by running

    sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:background_migrations:finalize[CopyColumnUsingBackgroundMigrationJob,events,id,'[["id"]\, ["id_convert_to_bigint"]]']

For more information, check the documentation

    https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/monitoring/background_migrations.html#database-migrations-failing-because-of-batched-background-migration-not-finished
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/migration_helpers.rb:1109:in `ensure_batched_background_migration_is_finished'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/post_migrate/20210622045705_finalize_events_bigint_conversion.rb:11:in `up'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/migrations/lock_retry_mixin.rb:31:in `ddl_transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/db.rake:61:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

Caused by:
Expected batched background migration for the given configuration to be marked as 'finished', but it is 'active':   {:job_class_name=>"CopyColumnUsingBackgroundMigrationJob", :table_name=>"events", :column_name=>"id", :job_arguments=>[["id"], ["id_convert_to_bigint"]]}

Finalize it manualy by running

    sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:background_migrations:finalize[CopyColumnUsingBackgroundMigrationJob,events,id,'[["id"]\, ["id_convert_to_bigint"]]']

For more information, check the documentation

    https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/monitoring/background_migrations.html#database-migrations-failing-because-of-batched-background-migration-not-finished
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/migration_helpers.rb:1109:in `ensure_batched_background_migration_is_finished'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/post_migrate/20210622045705_finalize_events_bigint_conversion.rb:11:in `up'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/migrations/lock_retry_mixin.rb:31:in `ddl_transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/db.rake:61:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
== 20210611082822 AddPagesFileEntriesToPlanLimits: migrating ==================
-- add_column(:plan_limits, :pages_file_entries, :integer, {:default=>200000, :null=>false})
   -> 0.0021s
== 20210611082822 AddPagesFileEntriesToPlanLimits: migrated (0.0022s) =========

== 20210622045705 FinalizeEventsBigintConversion: migrating ===================
STDERR:
---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20211028-68712-eysjor" ----
Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20211028-68712-eysjor" returned 1

Running handlers complete
Chef Infra Client failed. 27 resources updated in 51 seconds
===
There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure. Please check the output above for more
details.
===

dpkg: error processing package gitlab-ce (--configure):
 installed gitlab-ce package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gitlab-ce
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So as the output told me I tried :
`sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:background_migrations:finalize[CopyColumnUsingBackgroundMigrationJob,events,id,'[["id"]\, ["id_convert_to_bigint"]]']`

and got

```
rake aborted!
JSON::ParserError: unexpected character () at line 1, column 1 [parse.c:714]
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/json.rb:87:in `rescue in adapter_load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/json.rb:82:in `adapter_load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/json.rb:25:in `parse'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/background_migrations.rake:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

Caused by:
Oj::ParseError: unexpected character () at line 1, column 1 [parse.c:714]
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/json.rb:85:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/json.rb:85:in `adapter_load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/json.rb:25:in `parse'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/background_migrations.rake:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:background_migrations:finalize
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any idea ?

Comment: I suggest you to write a post on the Gitlab support platform, the only ones who solved me similar issues in the past.

Comment: @AntonioPetricca Thank you I have already done it

Answer (score 3):

After upgrading from 13 to 14.0 gitlab will commence several database migrations in the background (see yourgitlabserver.example.com/admin/background_migrations).

You have to wait for these to complete before advancing any further.

If you already did, there are several ways to fix this (see [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/monitoring/background_migrations.html#database-migrations-failing-because-of-batched-background-migration-not-finished)).

Comment: I had a very similar issue recently, going from 14.1 to 14.4 in which I believe that a short time between version updates did not allow background migrations to happen. Ultimately I rolled back the VM to a prior state, and went from  13.12.12 -> 14.0.11 -> 14.1.7 -> 14.4.1 allowing for time for background migrations (and a required restart of postgresql and redis services) and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error in this situation. To find out what's going on I've added following code into the
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/background_migrations.rake:17

```
      puts "JSON: '#{args[:job_arguments]}'"
```

to have the code looks like this:

```
      puts "JSON: '#{args[:job_arguments]}'"

      Gitlab::Database::BackgroundMigration::BatchedMigrationRunner.finalize(
        args[:job_class_name],
        args[:table_name],
        args[:column_name],
        Gitlab::Json.parse(args[:job_arguments])
      )
```

And I noticed that command `args[:job_arguments]` returns invalid JSON string.

So finally for me (zsh) worked to execute the following command:

```
sudo gitlab-rake 'gitlab:background_migrations:finalize[CopyColumnUsingBackgroundMigrationJob,events,id,[["id"]\, ["id_convert_to_bigint"]]]'
```

The difference is in single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Be warned that you may not see any background migrations at `gitlab.yoursite.com/admin/background_migrations` and yet be stuck at migrations. 
 It happened to me on 14.0.12

You should check `gitlab.yoursite.com/admin/health_check` for any "unhealthy" messages like:

```
"Current Status:  Not Healthy -- Migrations are pending. 
To resolve this issue, run: bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production 
You have 12 pending migrations"
```